Spark reads all parquet fields as nullable, except when written from Structured Streaming
The Spark docs are clear when reading parquet files that "When reading Parquet files, all columns are automatically converted to be nullable for compatibility reasons".
However I just noticed for a pipeline I'm developing using Spark Structured Streaming, that it seems like nullability information is being retained when I read the parquet files that have been written as part of the streaming job. Is this documented behaviour of Structured Streaming that I have just managed to miss?
The small pyspark examples below shows the behaviour; when we write out a DataFrame to Parquet in batch mode all fields are nullable when we read it back in, but when we write it out using spark structured streaming, fields that were marked as required in the streaming DataFrame remain required when we load the parquet files back in.
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
import time

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("sue", 32),
        ("li", 3),
        ("bob", None),
        ("heo", 13),
    ],
    ["first_name", "age"],
).withColumn("country", f.lit("UK"))

print("batch schema before written to parquet")
df.printSchema()
df.write.parquet("s3a://.../batch-write-test", mode="overwrite")

dfr = spark.read.parquet("s3a://.../batch-write-test")
print("batch schema after being read from parquet")
dfr.printSchema()

As expected, this prints out:
batch schema before written to parquet
root
 |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |-- country: string (nullable = false)

batch schema after being read from parquet
root
 |-- first_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |-- country: string (nullable = true)

However doing similar with the structued streaming API:
dfs = spark.readStream.format("rate").option("rowsPerSecond", 1).load().withColumn("country", f.lit("UK"))

print("streaming schema before written to parquet")
dfs.printSchema()

dfs.writeStream\
    .format("parquet")\
    .option("path", "s3a://.../stream-write-test/data")\
    .option("checkpointLocation", "s3a://.../stream-write-test/checkpoints")\
    .start()

time.sleep(5)
spark.streams.active[0].stop()

dfsr = spark.read.parquet("s3a://.../stream-write-test/data")

print("streaming schema after being read from parquet")
dfsr.printSchema()

results in the country column still being loaded as non-nullable:
streaming schema before written to parquet
root
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- value: long (nullable = true)
 |-- country: string (nullable = false)

streaming schema after being read from parquet
root
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- value: long (nullable = true)
 |-- country: string (nullable = false)

It doesn't look like this results from changes in how the files are written, using parquet-tools on an arbitrary file in each write shows the nullability info is included in the written schema, so there must be some difference in the read (although I've looked through the checkpoint/spark-metadata files output by the streaming job and can't see anywhere else it might be loading additional schema information from).
> parquet-tools schema ~/Downloads/part-00000-2af11246-d3eb-41c7-a1bc-148da0eb400a-c000.snappy.parquet | jq
{
  "Tag": "name=Spark_schema, type=STRUCT, repetitiontype=REQUIRED",
  "Fields": [
    {
      "Tag": "name=Timestamp, type=INT96, repetitiontype=OPTIONAL"
    },
    {
      "Tag": "name=Value, type=INT64, repetitiontype=OPTIONAL"
    },
    {
      "Tag": "name=Country, type=BYTE_ARRAY, convertedtype=UTF8, repetitiontype=REQUIRED"
    }
  ]
}
> parquet-tools schema ~/Downloads/part-00000-febecfc0-54c5-4646-a2ad-b9c30f6e4e60-c000.snappy.parquet | jq
{
  "Tag": "name=Spark_schema, type=STRUCT, repetitiontype=REQUIRED",
  "Fields": [
    {
      "Tag": "name=First_name, type=BYTE_ARRAY, convertedtype=UTF8, repetitiontype=OPTIONAL"
    },
    {
      "Tag": "name=Age, type=INT64, repetitiontype=OPTIONAL"
    },
    {
      "Tag": "name=Country, type=BYTE_ARRAY, convertedtype=UTF8, repetitiontype=REQUIRED"
    }
  ]
}


This might be a better one for the Spark mailing list, but this feels like it's probably documented somewhere that I've not found.
